# PHP Array tree structure to DB tree structure

Tags: php

I have a data structure in the PHP to connect to the switch using Telnet like this:

```
Array
(
    [172.1.1.2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [IP] => 172.1.1.1
                    [PlatformBrand] => dlink
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [IP] => 172.1.1.5
                    [PlatformBrand] => dlink
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [IP] => 172.1.1.7
                    [PlatformBrand] => dlink
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [IP] => 172.1.1.8
                    [PlatformBrand] => dlink
                )

        )

    [172.1.1.6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [IP] => 172.1.1.10
                    [PlatformBrand] => dlink
                )
        )

    [172.1.1.7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [IP] => 172.1.1.11
                    [PlatformBrand] => dlink
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [IP] => 172.1.1.14
                    [PlatformBrand] => dlink
                )
        )
)
```

but i want convert this into a tree like structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `network_equipment_class` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sort` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

id | ip         | parent | sort
--------------------------------
1  | 172.1.1.2  | 0      | 0
2  | 172.1.1.1  | 1      | 0
3  | 172.1.1.5  | 1      | 1
4  | 172.1.1.7  | 1      | 2
5  | 172.1.1.8  | 1      | 3
6  | 172.1.1.6  | 0      | 1
7  | 172.1.1.10 | 6      | 0
8  | 172.1.1.11 | 4      | 0
9  | 172.1.1.14 | 4      | 1
```

for PHP >= 5.3 to written function code, any idea or any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**
Here is my written code, but cannot be used:

```
function createDBTree($IP, $dbTree){
    if (!is_array($dbTree) || $dbTree == array()) {
        $dbTree = array('ip' => $IP);
    } else {
        foreach ($dbTree as $dbkey => $tmpdbvalue) {
            if(is_array($tmpdbvalue) && $arr !== array()) {
                if (!isset($tmpdbvalue['children'])) $dbTree = $this->createDBTree($IP, $tmpdbvalue['children']);
            } else {
                if ($tmpdbvalue['ip'] == $IP) $tmpdbvalue['children'] = array('ip' => $IP);
            }
        }
    }

    return $dbTree;
}
```

Finally, I will complete the structure:

```
172.1.1.2   =>  172.1.1.1
            =>  172.1.1.5
            =>  172.1.1.7   =>  172.1.1.11  =>  ... =>  ...
                            =>  172.1.1.14
                            =>  ...
            =>  172.1.1.8
            =>  ...

172.1.1.6   =>  172.1.1.10
            =>  ...

...
```

Comment: Start with a `foreach`. We will not write code for you here.

Comment: I have tried for a long time, but can not find the right written.

Comment: What's is the relation between the array and the desired output? How is `172.1.1.7` at id `4` a parent for `172.1.1.7` at id `8`? Edit: how are you getting this input?

Comment: sorry, I mistakenly wrote, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
$arr = array('172.1.1.2' => array(
                               array('IP' => '172.1.1.1','PlatformBrand' => 'dlink'),
                               array('IP' => '172.1.1.5','PlatformBrand' => 'dlink'),
                               array('IP' => '172.1.1.7','PlatformBrand' => 'dlink'),
                               array('IP' => '172.1.1.8','PlatformBrand' => 'dlink')
                              ),
             '172.1.1.6' => array(
                               array('IP' => '172.1.1.10','PlatformBrand' => 'dlink')
                              ), 
             '172.1.1.7' => array(
                               array('IP' => '172.1.1.11','PlatformBrand' => 'dlink'),
                               array('IP' => '172.1.1.14','PlatformBrand' => 'dlink')
                              ),                                 
            );                  
$sn = $parent = $sort = 0;
$hdr = "id  | ip  | parent  | sort\r\n";
$hdr .= "--------------------------------\r\n";
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
  $sn++;
  $hdr .= "$sn  | $k  | $parent  | $sort \r\n";
  $parent = $sn;  
  foreach($v as $t => $d){
   $sn++;
   $hdr .= "$sn  | {$d['IP']}  | $parent  | $sort \r\n";
   $sort++;
  }
  $parent = 0; 
  $sort = 0;   
}

echo nl2br($hdr);
```

Remember the array you have in your question is the output so you have to reformat it into PHP array before you iterate over it.

Of course you will not need the line breaks `"\n\r"` and `nl2br` if you are writing to database. Simply build up your query within the loop and execute.

Comment: I ran your code [here](https://3v4l.org/QFmPd), but 172.1.1.7 at id 4 a parent for 172.1.1.7 at id 8.

Comment: That's coming from your array; 172.1.1.7 is a child of 172.1.1.2 (first parent) and another 172.1.1.7 is a parent of 172.1.1.11 (3rd parent) - you may want to confirm that this is correct? My code focuses on the hierarchy of the provided array, but if you want a child to be a parent at the same time - you may need to introduce another array to track unique IPs in the main array.

Comment: The tree structure is must the result of the combined, but still thank you.